# How do I turn a list (with 1 item in it) into a variable?

Tags: python

I'm doing a python project and I don't know how to turn a list into a variable.
Here is my code so far:

```
list = ['Name1']
```

I want to turn the list into a variable. Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: You already put the list into a variable. But you should propably chose another name for the variable, such as "lst" because the "list" name is already occupied in python.

Comment: What do you mean by "turn a list into a variable"? If what you mean is how to create a variable `Name1` given the occurrence of the string `"Name1"` in a list, that would be a bad idea. It is possible to dynamically create variables but seldom a good idea to do so. Use a dictionary instead. In any event, it seems that you might need a tutorial in Python if you have questions about how to assign lists to variables. Stack Overflow really isn't a tutorial service. Better options exist (and are easy to find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
l = ['Name1']
name = l[0]
```

After this, `name` will be `'Name1'`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example using astype():

```
variable_string = list.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually change a list to a 'variable' as a list is already a variable.

You have kind of two paths.

1. Somehow get the index of the variable you want to get and pass this into a variable

E.g. If I wanted a first object in the list I would do:

```
my_variable = list[0]
```

2. Just use the list index as your variable

   print(list[0])